# Transition in flex-basis not working when using flex-wrap:wrap

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-transitions

I have been trying to do this animation with no success. Anybody has any clue how can I solve it?
Thanks

Here is my CSS:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.child {
  flex-basis: 30em;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: flex-basis 1000ms ease-in-out;
}

.child:hover {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

And my HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">Child 1</div>
  <div class="child">Child 2</div>
  <div class="child">Child 3</div>
  <div class="child">Child 4</div>
  <div class="child">Child 5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: just fyi, there is a typo: `fex-wrap`

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but your `.child` elements have `color: white` so you won't see much, unless you have some background color applied.

Comment: Thanks gru, just corrected the typo. Also I got rid of the color, that is not the matter. The problem is that the width of my childs are not growing to full width row when animating flex-basis to 100%

Comment: Your animation is working fine. I think we are just confused on what we are trying to achieve here. I added `border-right: 1px solid black;` to your `.child` class and everything works as I would expect when I hover an individual child. Did you want all of them to be 100% width on hover? If that is the case Arman has your answer.

Comment: ***I have been trying to do this animation with no success.*** What animation ?

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.child {
  flex-basis: 20%;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: white;
  transition: flex-basis 1000ms ease-in-out;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}

.container:hover .child {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">Child 1</div>
  <div class="child">Child 2</div>
  <div class="child">Child 3</div>
  <div class="child">Child 4</div>
  <div class="child">Child 5</div>
</div>
```